# Using multiple plugins in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

The plugin model in Backbone.js is really nice, but one thing I'm wondering about is whether it's possible to use multiple plugins without modifying any of the plugin source.

For example, say I've written two plugins for the `Collections`:

```
MyBetterCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    coolNewFeature: function () {
        console.log('This feature is great.');
    }

});

MyWayBetterCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    wayCoolerNewFeature: function () {
        console.log('This feature is even better.');
    }

});
```

I can see some potential issues already, if, for example, both plugins override something like the `add` method. But having to modify third-party plugins would be a bummer:

```
MyWayBetterCollection = MyBetterCollection.extend({
    ...
});
```

Is there a good approach to handling this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do this. Since there is no traditional inheritance in JavaScript, it's difficult to provide this facility.

You'd have to find plug ins designed to work with each other or fork them and make them compatible.

You could also provide your own extend method that would use the interceptor pattern or some type of monkey patching to provide access to overwritten methods from previous prototypes that were overwritten.

Comment: That was my impression as well, but I wanted to check it out. The rationale and limitations make sense, but this effectively limits you to using one plugin per object type, unless you want to assume responsibility for maintaining your own custom fork of a project. Disappointing.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of things like that in JavaScript I find.  This might interest you though: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html followed by this: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Answer (score -1):

The two collection you've defined above are totally separate from each other. They simply inherit the methods from Backbone.Controller, and if you defined methods with the similar name, then you overwrite those.

Think about Backbone as a class inheritance in other programming languages. Basically, you extend Backbone.Collection as you would do with other languages.

As a result, you can call the superclass, like this

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection({
    toJSON: function() {
        var toJSON = this.constructor.__super__.toJSON.call(this);
        toJSON.extra = 'my extra value';
        return toJSON;
    });
```

Even if you extend your own collection, the logic remains.

Comment: JavaScript has no `super`. Prototypal inheritance, specifically when you use `extend` from underscore/backbone specifically overwrites any name collisions and does NOT provide a way to call the previous version -- it's 100% gone. Let's see a jsfiddle showing how `__super__` exists and works. http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do understand that extending a `Backbone.Collection` will overwrite any methods that share the same name, which is kinda what prompted my question. I was wondering if there's a way to harmoniously meld multiple plugins that extend the same Backbone object. Sounds like there isn't.

Comment: @tkone, of course, there is no __super__ in Javascript, but there is in Backbone, at least the code above works as expected as long as you don't use the same name for your original and extended backbone objects

Comment: @akasha yeah, but given that it doesn't work 'the same' (wrt to overwritten names) it has a potentially confusion effect, especially I'd you're new to the language. The number of times I come back to js after writing python and try a for in loop is ridiculous enough as it is :)